# Authorisation problems when using google service account. Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup

Tags: python-3.x, google-fusion-tables, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I am writing a python wrapper for fusion tables.
I decided to use google service account for accessing the service. My code is:

```
import httplib2
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('__Remak APIS-37c11e21531ad.json', scopes)

http = httplib2.Http()

if not credentials.access_token:
    credentials.refresh(http)

service = build('fusiontables', 'v2', http=http)


def test():
    table_id = '1esH-YayZegZH69VsiVBq0YK9hxgP-JWTCljRuQUZy'

    print(service.query().sql(sql='SELECT * FROM {}'.format(table_id)).execute(http=http))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

the output is:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?alt=json&sql=SELECT+%2A+FROM+1esH-YayrtegZH6VsiVBq0YK9hxgP-JWTCljRuQUZy returned "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.">
```

I just enabled this API that is why the daily limit is for sure hasn't reached. I also tried to find the answer in similar topics, but I wasn't succeeded.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally made it work:
there were one part missed:

`credentials.authorize(http)`

Now it seems OK

The code is:

```
import httplib2

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables']
KEY = '__Remak APIS-a8cd56ca2b4e.json'
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(KEY,     scopes)
http = httplib2.Http()

credentials.authorize(http)

if not credentials.access_token:
    credentials.refresh(http)

fusiontables = build('fusiontables', 'v2', http=http)


def test():
    table_id = '1esH-YayZegZH97VsiVBq0YK9hxgP-JWTCljRuQUZy'

    print(fusiontables.query().sql(sql='SELECT * FROM     {}'.format(table_id)).execute())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```